# Wacom Bamboo Splash (CTL471) on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wacom, graphics-tablet

I recently bought a Wacom Bamboo Splash, and I can't get it to work on 12.04. The output of lsusb is as follows:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 064e:d104 Suyin Corp. 
Bus 005 Device 006: ID 1410:6002 Novatel Wireless 
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 056a:00dd Wacom Co., Ltd
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found this [here](http://www.traumflieger.de/forum/viewtopic.php?t=47385&sid=3c619a11a49c4b2d16b37742c9d2f718):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lekensteyn/wacom-tablet 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install dkms wacom-dkms
```

Tell me if it worked for you.

Comment: I'd already done that, and it didn't work.